# Android Studio: Theme Change - Empty Activity

Tags: android

I started a new empty activity. I am in the start of the project. By default my theme is set to AppTheme. I dont want the title bar on my theme. I changed the theme to NoTitleBar and lot of other themes. I am getting this error.

```
Missing styles. Is the correct theme chosen for this layout?  Use the Theme combo box above the layout to choose a different layout, or fix the theme style references.   Failed to find '?attr/textEditSuggestionItemLayout' in current theme. (9 similar errors not shown)  Tip: Try to refresh the layout.
```

I tried lot of other themes and I am getting errors like this. Is there a way I could select a theme where I dont want to have a title bar on my app?

If not, how can I change the color of my title bar and add a logo?

Answer (score 0):

chose holo light them from them box above the layout

Comment: It still has a title bar

Comment: android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"

Comment: Does not work!!! My question states the problem when I set the theme to the following you mentioned

Answer (score 0):

You mean, project name?
You can use NoActionBar if you dont want this code in your styles

```
 <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">

</style>
```